# Why is Modernizr loading Google fonts?

Tags: ssl, fonts, modernizr

I am building a web app and just installed ssl.

Everything seems to be fine except for these two errors I'm getting about fonts being loaded over an insecure connection.  The console suggests it's something that Modernizr is doing, but I can't figure out where and how to fix it.

Here's the console output:

```
The page at 'https://myawesomewebsite.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/rosarivo/v1/OGdIq-p0tOtBN2VMVvO9W_esZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
modernizr-2.8.0.min.js:4
The page at 'https://myawesomewebsite.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/inconsolata/v5/BjAYBlHtW3CJxDcjzrnZCIbN6UDyHWBl620a-IRfuBk.woff': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
modernizr-2.8.0.min.js:4
```

I am actually using TypeKit for my fonts, so I have no idea what these Google Fonts are doing on the page and why Modernizr would be loading them.

Answer (score 2):

There is a test for @font-face for CCS3 support in the full build of modernizr. I believe this test code loads some font just to see if that is working.

If you don't need that, use the build configurator on the modernizr page to exclude that from your custom built library.

By the way, it seems that the newer version of modernizr loads the fonts over SSL.

**Test Code in modernizr 2.8.3**

```
/*>>fontface*/
// @font-face detection routine by Diego Perini
// javascript.nwbox.com/CSSSupport/

// false positives:
//   WebOS github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/342
//   WP7   github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/538
tests['fontface'] = function() {
    var bool;

    injectElementWithStyles('@font-face {font-family:"font";src:url("https://")}', function( node, rule ) {
      var style = document.getElementById('smodernizr'),
          sheet = style.sheet || style.styleSheet,
          cssText = sheet ? (sheet.cssRules && sheet.cssRules[0] ? sheet.cssRules[0].cssText : sheet.cssText || '') : '';

      bool = /src/i.test(cssText) && cssText.indexOf(rule.split(' ')[0]) === 0;
    });

    return bool;
};
/*>>fontface*/

// CSS generated content detection
tests['generatedcontent'] = function() {
    var bool;

    injectElementWithStyles(['#',mod,'{font:0/0 a}#',mod,':after{content:"',smile,'";visibility:hidden;font:3px/1 a}'].join(''), function( node ) {
      bool = node.offsetHeight >= 3;
    });

    return bool;
};
```

Comment: Oh, I just wanted to say, though, that using the newest version did not fix the problem.  I have 2.8.3 now, with that very code, and it still loads the fonts over http and I can't figure out why.  Using this file: http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js
I'm getting that it's a problem at line 462, which confuses me tremendously, because that line is: `bool = node.offsetTop === 9;`

Comment: Hrmppf, good to know. I was deceived by the "https://". And you are right. They use a lot of black magic in there. ;o)

Comment: Having the same issue.  Modernizr isn't loading any http directly.  However, I did find these odd fonts in my jtable plugin.  Once I fixed these fonts in the jtable css pages it was fixed.  My guess is modernizr is doing what it is suppose to.  It would be nice though if Modernizr could upgrade the http to https.